# get default fieldset border width cross browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, border, fieldset

example http://jsfiddle.net/fuZ4L/

I am trying to get the border width of a fieldset using:

```
$("fieldset").css("borderWidth")
```

and it works fine in chrome and opera but ie and firefox return a blank string.

Is there another way to get the default border width of a fieldset or is this an error in jQuery?

Comment: Use `border-top-width` since shorthand for `border-width` is not widely supported http://jsfiddle.net/moogs/y7Jsf/2/

Comment: thanks that works. According to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-width every major browser has supported border-width for quite a while.

Comment: Yes correct but what I meant is accessing the `border-width` property from JavaScript, not the CSS property itself